# Using custom tag in activity file of Paf scripts

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While adding custom tag in activity file,i am getting error that custom tag not found in activity how to resolve this while scripting in pace automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to add the custom.jar file in dependencies.
For this click on the dropdown next to the Run button on the IDE
and select “Run Configurations…”
Select any of the java application from left pane
select the tab arguments ->Dependencies--->select class path entries-->click on add external jars button
select the custom jar file from the lib folder and add to dependencies. click on 'Run' button